# How to use filesystem as semaphore

Tags: vbscript, clipboard

I have several script trying to access the clipboard. Only, one script at a time can access the clipboard at a time. My solution did not work. Here is the solution I implemented

- check if clipboardLock.txt exists.
- -if it does not exist then create it
- --do processes
- -if it does exist then wait 3 seconds to 10 seconds and check if it exists

This did not work well because two scripts tried to create the file and errored out. Is there a technique to guarantee only one script can access the clipboard? Also, I do not have access to a database.

Comment: As there is no read lock in VBScript (@Steve, -1), you have to write-open the semaphore file or use renaming to control access. In both cases you must handle possible errors. Did you trap errors in your script?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Doing check then act (steps 1 and 2 above) is always going to be a race. You should skip the check, just attempt the act, and react to errors appropriately.

Comment: @Luke101 - I believe Damien's advice is sound. As I mentioned before, decent error handling is a prerequisite. What did you do wrt to errors in your failed attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having the scripts create a file, have them open an existing file in exclusive mode (that is, no one else can open it).  If the file opens processing can proceed, otherwise the script must wait.

In order to open the file exclusively, you can use [OpenTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to open it for writing:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting)
```

Once the processing is complete, close the file so that other scripts can attempt to open the file.

Comment: This is not working for me. I think because I have windows 7 64bit.  I believe I read somewhere that vbscript works different on 64bit systems

Answer (score 0):

Using your method, vbscript does not block on ForWriting and wait until the file is closed.  Launch the following script twice ... first leaving the msgbox "File Open..." open ... then launch again.  You'll get "Permission Denied" and the second script will break.  On Error Resume Next will defeat the objective of waiting for the file to become available before proceeding.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("c:\somefile.txt", ForWriting, True) 
wscript.echo "File Open..."
filetxt.Close
wscript.echo "Done..."
```

So I see there are 4 upvotes ... how did this possibly work?

Here's a working routine - just sit in while loop until the file becomes available:

```
lockFile

sub lockFile ()
    Dim fso, LockFile, LockFileName, done
    Const ForWriting = 2

    LockFileName = "C:\somefile.lck"
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    done = false
    on error resume next 'need to evaluate error 

    while (not(done))
        err.clear
        Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(LockFileName, ForWriting, True) 
        if (err.number = 0) then 
            done = true
        else
            done = false
        end if
        wscript.echo "Error [0=file open, 70=file in use] : " & err.number
        wscript.sleep(1000) 'wait one second instead of chewing up CPU
    wend

    wscript.echo "File Open..."
    filetxt.Close
    wscript.echo "Done..."

    on error goto 0 'reset error level

end sub
```