# Run VBScript Consecutively

Tags: vbscript

I have on Outlook rule that kicks off a batch statement which starts a VBScript that then kicks off other VBScripts based on the sender and subject heading.  If two emails from the same sender come into the in box simultaneously, it will start the first instance correctly.  However, the second will kick off and return an error stating "Permission denied".  I would like to run each email consecutively.

I have already tried the sleep functions and other time bound delays, but the query times are not consistent due to the size of the data.

Here is the basic script I have been using.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set olMAPI = olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set oFolder = olMAPI.Folders("FieldFinanceAutomatedReports@xxxxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Requested Report People")
Set allEmails = oFolder.Items 
Set firstemail = allEmails.GetLast

unreadCount = 0 
For Each email In oFolder.Items 
    If email.Unread = True Then 
        If email.Sender= "Sender_of_email@email.com" Then
            Set objcreate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objread = objcreate.OpenTextFile("C:\path_to_script\script.vbs")
            request = objread.ReadAll()
            objread.Close
            Set objread = Nothing
            Execute request
            Set request = Nothing
            Set objcreate = Nothing
        End If
        WScript.Sleep 500

        If email.Sender = "Another_Sender_of_email@email.com" Then
            Set objcreate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objread = objcreate.OpenTextFile("C:\path_to_script\another_script.vbs")
            another_request = objread.ReadAll()
            objread.Close
            Set objread = Nothing
            Execute another_request
            Set another_request = Nothing
            Set objcreate = Nothing
        End If
        WScript.Sleep 500

        unreadCount = unreadCount + 1 
    End If 
Next
```

I would like for each of the instances to wait until it the first process is complete.

Comment: What you need is called a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) or [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). Have your script [create a temp file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14225922/1630171) when it enters a critical section (where you don't want concurrent execution) and repeat that in a loop until it succeeds (no error occurs). Remove that file after the critical section.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) or [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). Essentially that's a resource that can be held by only one process or thread at a time. In VBScript you could implement that by attempting to [create a (temporary) file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14225922/1630171). First process to do that wins, subsequent attempts will fail because the file already exists.

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\mutex.txt")

'this will throw an error if the file is already opened
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, True)
```

Note that you need to open the file for writing (second parameter set to 2). Opening it for reading (second parameter set to 1) does not suffice.

Run the operation in a loop and you can wait for another process to finish and release the mutex.

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\mutex.txt")

On Error Resume Next
Do
    Err.Clear
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, True)
    If Err Then WScript.Sleep 100
Loop While Err
On Error Goto 0
```

Make sure you remove the file when your script leaves the critical section (or terminates), otherwise other scripts might have trouble acquiring the mutex later. A convenient way of doing this is to implement the mutex as a class. That way it will automatically be cleaned up, even if the script should terminate unexpectedly.

```
Class Mutex
    Private f_

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        filename = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\mutex.txt")

        On Error Resume Next
        Do
            Err.Clear
            Set f_ = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, True)
            If Err Then WScript.Sleep 100
        Loop While Err
        On Error Goto 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        f_.Close
    End Sub
End Class
```

You use that `Mutex` class in your code like this:

```
Set m = New Mutex   'acquire mutex
'...
'critical section goes here
'...
Set m = Nothing     'release mutex
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. I'm curious though why use `IsEmpty()` instead of just capturing the error generated by the lock on the file? Something like `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` or even the specific error? Just wonder what would happen if `Err` returned a permission error instead for example. Regardless it's a great answer. +1

Comment: @Lankymart `Err` should have a permission error (error 70, permission denied) when the file is already opened. But you're right, I should've used the same condition for both sleep and loop termination. Fixed. If one wanted to make the condition more specific (to distinguish between different error types) they could check `Err.Number = 70` instead of just the presence of an error.